# I am trying to create an updating title (views and likes) for my YouTube video

Tags: api, google-api, youtube-api

But it does not get updated, I have the youtube API and it seems this is the problem.
is it the problem with calling the API? or?
I am lost!!
This is the code down below.

```
function myFunction() {
  function updateTitle() {
  
  var videoID = '-------------'; //----------------------
  var part = 'snippet,statistics';
  var params = {'id': videoID};
  var response = YouTube.Videos.list(part, params);
  var video = response.items[0];
  var videoViewsCount = video.statistics.viewCount;
  var videoLikeCount = video.statistics.likeCount;
  var videoTitle = 'OMG this video has ' + videoViewsCount + ' veiws and ' + videoLikeCount + ' likes!!!';
  video.snippet.title = videoTitle;
  try{
    YouTube.Videos.update(video, part);
  }catch(e){
 }
}
}
```

## error

> 8:35:14 PM Error GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota). updateTitle @ updateTitle.gs:8

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: 8:35:14 PM Error 
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.
updateTitle @ updateTitle.gs:8

Comment: Well if your getting a quota error then its not going to be updated. You need to wait until tomrrow.

Comment: is it that if I run the code tomorrow then it will work?

Answer (score 1):

> The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.

Error means exactly that you have exceeded your quota.

You can check your current quota by going to google developer console. click library on the left search for youtube data api.  Then manage then check the quota tab

[image]

Youtube api has a cost based quota system.  your making to many requests.

- [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) request for an extension.
- [Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc)